# Creating Custom YAML file using SnakeYAML or Jackson

Tags: java, android, yaml, snakeyaml

I am trying to generate a YAML file in this format using Java on an Android app:

```
testConfig: [
  {test1: "example1", test2: "example2"},
  {test3: "example3", test4: "example4"},
]
```

How can I make this programmatically using either SnakeYAML or Jackson using **Java** on **Android**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution - I just formatted a YAML file with Strings and therefore didn't need SnakeYAML or Jackson.